# FTP with TLS doesn't work, nor can I change port in pure-ftpd

Tags: linux, networking, ftp

I have been having problems with my ftp server that I have tried fixing for over a week now.

#### My configuration:

- I am running Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi.
- My ftp server is pure-ftpd, and I'm running it with these switches:

> /usr/local/sbin/pure-ftpd -D -C 5 -E -A -H -x -p 35000:36000 -u 0 -y
> 5:3 -Y 1

- I have compiled it with the option "--with-tls"
- I am using **explicit TLS encryption**, (I have also tried implicit, same result)
- I have port forwarded my passive port range as defined by the -p switch in pure-ftpd
- I have also port forwarded port 20 to 21

#### Other servers I'm running:

- A samba server
- An Apache web server
- Custom Python socket server
- and the built in shh/sftp server

I also have the no-ip DUC client running

#### In short here are the problems I'm having with pure-ftpd:

- FTP in LAN without TLS (Active and Passive): Working
- FTP in LAN with TLS (Active and Passive): Working
- FTP in WAN without TLS (Passive): Working
- FTP in WAN with TLS (Active and Passive): Not working
- Can't change port as it won't work in WAN

Here are the error logs and the things I have tried:

ftptest.net results (**for FTP with tls**):

> ........
>
> Command: PASV
>
> Reply: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,4,138,78)
>
> Error: Server returned unroutable private IP address in PASV reply

I have read on forums that you have to specify PASV IP address with the -P switch, so I did, and this is the result:

> Reply: 211-Extensions supported:
>
> .....................
>
> Error: Carriage return without line feed received

And this is for **both without and with tls!** So yeah, the -P switch doesn't work at all!

I should also point out that the passive mode ports are correct (taken from PASV command)

Filezilla log (with explicit tls):

> Command:  PASV
>
> Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,4,138,251)
>
> Status:   Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using
> server address instead.
>
> Command:  MLSD
>
> Error:    The data connection could not be established: ECONNREFUSED -
> Connection refused by server
>
> Error:    Connection closed by server
>
> Error:    Failed to retrieve directory listing

With -P switch:

Same thing except no "Server sent unrouteable address*"

I have also tried messing with the firewall (iptables), by allowing everything (thus, disabling the firewall) with these commands:

```
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

I also cannot change the default port, because if I do, I get a connection refused error.

And I have yet another strange symptom that just started appearing today:

I can only open port 21 to 21 (it works) because if I open up 20, I get the ssh server.

Log for that:

> Status: Connected, waiting for welcome message... Reply:
>
> SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
>
> Error: Reply does not contain valid response code

I also tried port forwarding port 443, 989 to 990 (that was for implicit tls) and I tried setting the Raspberry Pi as a DMZ host.

Note: I switched from vsftpd as it was slow and did not support secure ftp (the 3.x for Raspberry Pi needs to be compiled with secure ftp support, but I got an error compiling) , and I don't use proftpd because it couldn't compile with tls support

/var/log/messages does not provide any helpful information (only says that user is logged in every time with or without tls)

Hopefully you guys can help me out here as I am really lost!

Comment: If you have found an answer, then **post it as an answer,** below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IT IS FINALLY SOLVED!** All i had to do was to change my passive port range from 50000-51000 to 12000-13000! Now everything works great!!!
I am now using pure-ftpd like this:

> /usr/local/sbin/pure-ftpd -D -C 5 -E -A -H -x -S 192.168.0.4,60 -p 12000:13000 -u 0 -y 5:3 -Y 1 -P &